# How to sort scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix according to result of another function?

Tags: python, sorting, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I am learning about machine learning, more precisely about logistic regression / classification. In my code I have a `<class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>` object. I need to sort this sparse matrix, or the `SFrame` from which it was generated (using ...) according to the result of `LogisticRegression.predict_proba`, to be precise the second column the arrays, which are contained in the resulting array of `predict_proba`.

How I generated the sparse matrix:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

products = sframe.SFrame('...')

train_data, test_data = products.random_split(.8, seed=1)

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(token_pattern=r'\b\w+\b')
test_matrix = vectorizer.transform(test_data['review_clean'])
```

How I calculate the probabilities:

```
sentiment_model.predict_proba(test_matrix)
```

(where sentiment_model is a learned classifier, using logistic regression)
This gives me a `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`, which looks like this:

```
[[  4.65761066e-03   9.95342389e-01]
 [  9.75851270e-01   2.41487300e-02]
 [  9.99983374e-01   1.66258341e-05]]
```

Here is an example for what the SFrame data looks like, if I print it using the `print` function:

```
+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+--------+
|              name             |             review            | rating |
+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+--------+
|   Our Baby Girl Memory Book   | Absolutely love it and all... |  5.0   |
| Wall Decor Removable Decal... | Would not purchase again o... |  2.0   |
| New Style Trailing Cherry ... | Was so excited to get this... |  1.0   |
+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+--------+
+-------------------------------+-----------+
|          review_clean         | sentiment |
+-------------------------------+-----------+
| Absolutely love it and all... |     1     |
| Would not purchase again o... |     -1    |
| Was so excited to get this... |     -1    |
+-------------------------------+-----------+
```

So I'd need some function, which can sort that matrix, depending on the results of the predict_proba function.

**Question**: How can I sort it like that?

#### What I already tried

```
sorted(test_matrix)
```

results in:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().
```

---

```
sorted(test_matrix_complete, key=lambda x: sentiment_model.predict_proba(x))
```

also results in:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

---

The main problem is, that I don't know how to make the connection between the SFrame's data and the sparse matrix efficiently, I guess.

Comment: You can't in general use Python list operations on a sparse matrix.  And most numpy functions don't work as well.  You must use scipy sparse ones

Comment: There are lots of questions about that valueerror; see the side board.  You using an array in a context that expects a simple boolean true/false. Most likely because are trying to sort the matrix with list tool.

Comment: There isn't a scipy sparse sort

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply index by the sorted indices of `result`.

```
sorted_matrix = test_matrix[np.argsort(result)]
```